# Hashicorp Vault KV store version 2 inaccessible using hashi_vault Ansible plugin

Tags: ansible, hashicorp-vault

I'm trying to access some Vault kv secrets in my Ansible playbook...

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: Retrieve secret/hello using native hashi_vault plugin
      debug: msg="{{ lookup('hashi_vault', 'secret=secret/my-secret:foo token={{ vault_token }} url={{ vault_address }} ')}}"
```

I'm finding this works fine where secret/my-secret is stored using version one of the kv store engine. However, when using version two I see the following error...

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'hashi_vault'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: The secret secret/my-secret doesn't seem to exist for hashi_vault lookup"}
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is version two of the kv engine just not supported by the hasi_vault lookup plugin?

Cheers!

Mark

Comment: Try `secret=secret/data/my-secret:foo`

Comment: Interesting. I tried that and now I'm getting a slightly different error...

`fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'hashi_vault'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: The secret secret/data/my-secret does not contain the field 'foo'. for hashi_vault lookup"}`

Comment: Okay, this seems to work, not sure if it's the best way to do it though!

```---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    secret: "{{ lookup('hashi_vault', 'secret=secret/data/my-secret:data') }}"
  tasks:
    - name: Retrieve secret/hello using native hashi_vault plugin
      debug: msg="{{ secret['foo'] }}"```

Comment: So in KV2 the API changed such that the endpoint is now `<usually secret>/data/<field>` and returns a JSON with `data` as the top level key, and `data` and `metadata` as nested keys. Your KV pair lives in `data`. The python bindings to Vault's REST API then require the usage update you implemented. Check the documentation here: https://www.vaultproject.io/api/secret/kv/kv-v2.html#read-secret-version. I can write this up in an answer.

Comment: hey, do you got the solution w.r.t kv2 engine

Answer (score 10):

There is an pull request open for this: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/41132

I use a slight variation of your workaround:

```
password: "{{ lookup('hashi_vault', 'secret=secret/data/my_secret:data')['password']}}"
```

That way you only need to modify one line.